# can't delete y axis label in plot.gbm

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels, gbm

Run-on question following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634252/r-axis-widths-in-gbm-plot) problem setting axis widths in gbm.plot; I'm now using plot.gbm directly and don't seem to be able to remove the y axis label, which seems to be set within the plot.gbm function code.

```
png(filename="name.png",width=4*480, height=4*480, units="px", pointsize=80, bg="white", res=NA, family="", type="cairo-png")
par(mar=c(2.6,2,0.4,0.5), fig=c(0,1,0.1,1), las=1, lwd=8, bty="n", mgp=c(1.6,0.5,0))
plot.gbm(my_gbm_model,1,return.grid=FALSE, write.title=F,lwd=8, ylab=F, axes=F, ylabel=FALSE, ylabel="")
      axis(1, lwd.ticks=8, lwd=8, labels=FALSE) 
      axis(2, lwd.ticks=8, lwd=8, labels=NA, ylab=FALSE,ylabel=FALSE) 
dev.off()
```

Result:
[image: yaxislabel]

The y axis label is still there despite all my atempts to remove it through `par` and `plot` and `axis`. I could try burrowing into the function and changing this (and similar) lines:

```
print(stripplot(X1 ~ temp | X2 * X3, data = X.new, 
    xlab = x$var.names[i.var[i[1]]], 
    ylab = paste("f(", paste(x$var.names[i.var[1:3]], collapse = ","), ")", sep = ""),
    ...))
```

...but [I've been advised against such practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629531/r-burrow-into-function-to-change-it-with-trace). Any thoughts why this might be working? Simply that the function overrides the setting?

Reproducibility:

```
#core data csv: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6LsdZetdypkWnBJVDJ5U3l4UFU
#(I've tried to make these data reproducible before and I can't work out how to do so)
library(dismo)
samples <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, row.names=NULL) 
my_gbm_model <- gbm.step(data=samples, gbm.x=1:6, gbm.y=7, family = "bernoulli", 
    tree.complexity = 2, learning.rate = 0.01, bag.fraction = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `plot.gbm` just isn't a very R-like function. Since anyone can submit a package to CRAN it's not required that they follow traditional R patterns and that looks like what happened here. If you step though `plot.gbm` with your sample data, you see that ultimately the plotting is done with

```
plot(X$X1, X$y, type = "l", xlab = x$var.names[i.var], ylab = ylabel)
```

and the `ylabel` is set immediately before with no option to disable it. The authors simply provided no standard way to suppress the `ylab` for this particular plotting function.

In this case the easiest way might just be to reduce the left margin so the label prints off the plot. Seems like

```
par("mar"=c(5,2.2,4,2)+.1, fig=c(0,1,0.1,1), las=1, lwd=8, bty="n")
plot.gbm(my_gbm_model,1,return.grid=FALSE, write.title=F,lwd=8, ylab="", axes=F)
axis(1, lwd.ticks=8, lwd=8, labels=FALSE) 
axis(2, lwd.ticks=8, lwd=8, labels=FALSE)
```

[image]